# Are Docker questions off-topic?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, scope

Are Docker questions on-topic? A question was closed some time ago: [Java instances on Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405059/java-instances-on-docker).
Since Docker doesn't relate to programming, should the tag be deleted?

Should a new one, [dockerfile](/questions/tagged/dockerfile), be added? This tag would be about the files that are used with Docker instances, and I don't see this as ontopic at Server Fault.

Comment: OT is on-topic or off-topic?

Comment: @Bart Ontopic, editing. Don't agree with your edit, though. The last line should stay, as it is most likely the only thing keeping my question from being marked as already asked.

Comment: Meh, have it your way. Adding a disclaimer doesn't make a question any more or less a duplicate.

Comment: Uhh, what is docker? [This](https://www.docker.io/)? Why exactly would that be off-topic? It sounds like a tool that would be "commonly used by programmers", *especially* if asked in conjunction with a programming language like Java.

Comment: "OT" is in [the glossary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/256420#256420).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question wasn't closed due to what it contained, it was closed due to what it *didn't* contain. Granted, background on the topic might give me some additional insight into what you were trying to accomplish, thus ask, however the question seems to be very vague to me.

Questions about tools that programmers commonly use *for programming* are very much on topic, however you might need to give a bit more context if you're talking about a tool that:

- Not many have used before
- Is being used in a very interesting way, a way that not many have used it before

Regarding the tag, if you really think it's appropriate to label questions concerning a Docker configuration file among more general questions about the tool, then it would make sense; notice that we have the [git](/questions/tagged/git) and [gitignore](/questions/tagged/gitignore) tags for similar reasons.

While your question seems perfectly clear to you, it didn't seem that clear to the folks that closed it, so just try to give more background into the actual problem that you're having and what you're trying to do. Reading your question a few times, I got the sense that you were more or less thinking out loud - and it's fine to show a brainstorm in the question as long as your problem and goal are very clear.

I don't see a need to restore your previous post, go ahead and just ask a new question.

Comment: Alright. I removed what I was using Java for and bam, it was reopened (then closed later on), so that's how I came to the conclusion.